# Prove that $\frac{d}{dt} (\vec{r} \cdot (\vec{r}' \times \vec{r}'') = \vec{r} \cdot (\vec{r}' \times \vec{r}''')$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have $\frac{d}{dt} (\vec{r} \cdot (\vec{r}' \times \vec{r}'') \\
= \vec{r}' \cdot (\vec{r}' \times \vec{r}'') + \vec{r} \cdot (\vec{r}' \times \vec{r}'')'\\
=\vec{r}' \cdot (\vec{r}' \times \vec{r}'')+ \vec{r} \cdot (\vec{r}' \times \vec{r}''')$

Now I don't know what to do because i think when a vector is in form $a \cdot (b \times c)$, then I need to use triple determinant. But I can't because I don't have components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think geometrically.
$$\vec{r}' \cdot (\vec{r}' \times \vec{r}'')$$

The cross product results in a new vector, say $\vec{v}$, which is by construction perpendicular to $\vec{r}' $and $\vec{r}''$.

What can you say about $\vec{r}'\cdot \vec{v}$ then?

Comment: They equal 0 because $\vec{v}$ is perpendicular to the plane of $\vec{r}'$?

Comment: Yeah, and that stems from the definition of a dot product. $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{u}=||v|| ||u||\cos\theta$

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: @Pallas. Sure thing. Also, check out Vikasy's answer. He or she makes a good point about using the product rule. Your work checks out, though, as one of the product rule terms will vanish.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\vec{r}' \cdot (\vec{r}' \times \vec{r}'')=\det(\vec{r}',\vec{r}',\vec{r}'')=0$$ because there are two rows (or columns) equal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as others said $u.(u \times w) = 0$. Also, $(a \times b)' = (a' \times b) + (a \times b')$, where $u, v, w, a, b$ are vectors. Using these you can fix the third line of your answer.